# What does pragma keylist keyword do?

Tags: c++, pragma, iot, data-distribution-service

While reading about various IoT messaging protocols I came across a structure defined as below:

```
enum TempScale {
   CELSIUM,
   KELVIN,
   FARENHEIT
};

struct TempSensorType {
   short id;
   float temp;
   float hum;
   TempScale scale;
};
#pragma keylist TempSensorType id
```

My question is: What does this *#pragma keylist* keyword do and where can I find some documentation about using *#pragma* preprocessor directives (I believe it is such directive..).

Thanks.

Comment: Which particular compiler (version)?

Comment: Any use of `#pragma` is **strictly implementation defined**. Indeed that is the *purpose* of `#pragma`. So the **only** place any `#pragma` *could* be documented is the compiler manual. (That `#pragma` is strictly non-portable should be obvious.)

Comment: Thanks DevSolar. This made me look into clang and gcc documentation and search there for pragmas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The #pragma you are looking at is the PrismTech method for defining a key value within an OMG-DDS (Data Distribution Service for Real-Time Systems) Type structure.  In this case, it is defining the short 'id' as a key value.  The comparable RTI definition would be

```
struct TempSensorType {
    short id; //@key
    float temp;
    float hum;
    TempScale scale;
}
```

For interoperability between vendors' implementations, you can safely do

```
struct TempSensorType {
    short id; //@key
    float temp;
    float hum;
    TempScale scale;
}
#pragma keylist TempSensorType id
```

because the RTI compiler ignores the pragmas, and the PT compiler ignores the //@key.

This will change with future versions of the specification for Extensible Types, which will define a standard method for all vendors to support.

Note that if you were looking at a generic list of IoT messaging protocols, the concept of a "key" value may not exist in the other messaging protocols you were looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for DDS implementations that comply with the recently-adopted OMG DDS-XTYPES specification (http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS-XTypes/) the standard portable way to specify keys is either:

```
struct SensorType {
    @key short id;
    float temp;
    float hum;
    TempScale scale;
}
```

Or alternatively (to avoid breaking IDL compilers that do not understand the IDL annotations):

```
struct SensorType {
    short id; //@key
    float temp;
    float hum;
    TempScale scale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the explicit key-list specification via the pragma allows to define a ordering in the keys which - depending on the use-case - could have noticable performance impact on maintaining (filling/reading/querying/filtering) the 'multi-dimensional-storage' for a dataReader (and/or durability-service)